# DMM Spec Sheet Trouble

Tags: multimeter, specifications

I am wondering what the "Transfer" column indicates in this spec sheet for the Keithley Model 2002 DMM, and how it should be incorporated into any uncertainty calculations.

Thank You!

[image: Keithley Model 2002 DMM Spec Sheet for Ohms]

Comment: What does note 14 say?

Comment: Note 14. Specifications apply for 20-reading repeat digital filter, TREF ± 0.5°C (TREF is the initial
ambient temperature), and for measurements within 10% of the initial measurement value
and within 10 minutes of the initial measurement time.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer accuracy is how closely the meter will read compared to a calibration reference during a very short interval (often 10 minutes) and with stable temperature (as specified).

It's basically short-term repeatability.

Comment: It is 10 minutes as specified in note 14 which was added after your post.